# App is crash when I show data of DB in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

My app crashes when I want to show sone data in my listview.

```
package com.example.sqliteapplication;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsMerge extends Activity  {
    private ImageButton btn;
    private ImageButton imgb;
    private TemplateOperation templateDBoperation;
    ArrayList<User> arr;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms_merge);
        templateDBoperation = new TemplateOperation(this);
        templateDBoperation.open();
        List<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
         values = templateDBoperation.getAllTemplate();
         Object[] obj=values.toArray();

         arr=new ArrayList<User>();
         String[] da=new String[obj.length];
         for(int i=0; i<obj.length; i++)
        {
             da[i]=(String)obj[i];
             arr.add(new User(da[i]));
        }


        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Siddiqueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+obj.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
MyListAdapter adpttt=new MyListAdapter(SmsMerge.this,R.layout.row,arr);

listview.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        listview.setAdapter(adpttt);
        imgb=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnaddtemplate);
        imgb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SmsMerge.this, SqliteActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }   
        });


}
```

my custom adapter code is here....

```
package com.example.sqliteapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

    int inflatr;
    Context ctxt;
    ArrayList<User> data=new ArrayList<User>();
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<User> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.inflatr = layoutResourceId;
        this.ctxt = context;
        this.data= data;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        UserHolder holder = null;
         View row = convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctxt).getLayoutInflater();
              row = inflater.inflate(inflatr, parent, false);
             holder = new UserHolder();
             holder.textName=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);
             holder.btnEdit = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_removePay);
             row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
             holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();            
        }


        User dta=data.get(position);

            holder.textName.setText(dta.getName());
        holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        return row;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

}
```

my Template Class is here...

```
package com.example.sqliteapplication;

public class Template {
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String Description;
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setDescription(String Description) {
            this.Description = Description;
        }
        public String getDescription()
        {
            return Description;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

MY Database wraper code is here.....

```
package com.example.sqliteapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseWraper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TEMPLATE = "template";
    public static final String TEMPLATE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String PERSON_NAME = "_name";
    public static final String TEMPLATE_DESCRIPTION = "_description";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Template.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_Trmplate = "create table "
            + TEMPLATE + "(" + TEMPLATE_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + PERSON_NAME
            + " text not null, "+ TEMPLATE_DESCRIPTION
            + " text not null);";

    public DataBaseWraper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_Trmplate);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // you should do some logging in here
        // ..

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TEMPLATE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

My Template Operetion code is here

```
package com.example.sqliteapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class TemplateOperation {
    // Database fields
    private DataBaseWraper dbHelper;
    private String[] TEMPLATE_TABLE_COLUMNS = { DataBaseWraper.TEMPLATE_ID,
            DataBaseWraper.PERSON_NAME, DataBaseWraper.TEMPLATE_DESCRIPTION };
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public TemplateOperation(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DataBaseWraper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public Template addTemplate(String Description, String Person_Name) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DataBaseWraper.PERSON_NAME, Person_Name);
        values.put(DataBaseWraper.TEMPLATE_DESCRIPTION, Description);

        long templateId = database.insert(DataBaseWraper.TEMPLATE, null, values);

        // now that the student is created return it ...
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseWraper.TEMPLATE,
                TEMPLATE_TABLE_COLUMNS, DataBaseWraper.TEMPLATE_ID + " = "
                        + templateId, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        Template newComment = parseTemplate(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newComment;
    }

    public void deleteStudent(Template comment) {
        long id = comment.getId();
        System.out.println("Comment deleted with id: " + id);
        database.delete(DataBaseWraper.TEMPLATE, DataBaseWraper.TEMPLATE_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
    }

    public List getAllTemplate() {
        List students = new ArrayList();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseWraper.TEMPLATE,
                TEMPLATE_TABLE_COLUMNS, null, null, null, null,
                null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Template student = parseTemplate(cursor);
            students.add(student);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        Log.d(""+students, "humayoonnnnn");
        return students;
    }

    private Template parseTemplate(Cursor cursor) {
        Template template = new Template();
        template.setId((cursor.getInt(0)));
        template.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        return template;
    }

}
```

The stacktrace for the error:

```
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqliteapplication/com.example.sqliteapplication.SmsMerge}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.sqliteapplication.Template cannot be cast to java.lang.String
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.sqliteapplication.Template cannot be cast to java.lang.String
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at com.example.sqliteapplication.SmsMerge.onCreate(SmsMerge.java:43)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
05-08 18:44:03.336: E/AndroidRuntime(10100):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please paste only the needed code. By pasting everything it shows that you are not even trying to narrow down your issue. The problem comes from startIntent line 43 in SMSMerge, the error is self-describing.

Comment: tl;dr. see http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Template casting issue then I upload plz tell me what i do for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `da[i]=(String)obj[i];` is what it all comes down to.

The error already states:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.sqliteapplication.Template cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String

In other words: You cant cast your `Template`-Object to `String`.

**edit**
An alterantive would be using `obj[i].toString()`. 
In this case you could overwrite the `toString()`-Method for each class stored in the Object-Array, so that the returned output makes sense.

Comment: plzz tel me alternative way for this

Comment: try da[i]=obj[i].tostring(); (I see your Template class overrides tostring(), and I'm suspecting that your string cast is an attempt to get the value tostring() returns.

Comment: "... for each **object** stored in the Object-Array ..." classes are not objects, but the definition of one. An object is an instance of a class.

Comment: Samus Arin: I mean like each individual Class implementation should overwrite toString properly - as there are multiple different class types stored as Object